# Calculate difference between two dates( String format) in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

My Client stores the visit time of a page in MySQL as varchar. He is taking the object of date class `new date()` from JS which is off the format

> Fri Nov 25 2016 12:09:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

I want to calculate the time difference of 2 variables as shown above. It's used for the analytics purpose, time spent in a page like.

I already tried this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 'Fri Nov 25 2016 12:09:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', 
'Fri Nov 25 2016 12:20:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)')
```

How can I Do it?

Comment: Why varchar, doesn't MySQL have any proper date/time data types?

Comment: " last login time in MySQL in, varChar" Sometimes I ask myself why mySQL implemented a "date" type, when 90 % of the users just don't care about and continue to use varchar.. especially when the date comes from date(). 
I can't answer your question, don't know how to achieve it. May momentjs would solve the problem easy, because you shold be able to transform your varchar back in dateformat with it. Then is shouldn't be to difficult to calculate the difference.

Comment: It is colume holds different types of data,like ID, tags, or URLs, one of it is StatDate and EndDate.

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php

Comment: Does MySQL even support timestamps with timezone? I strongly recommend to treat that string as a string in the database and nothing more. Don't try to interprete it somehow, as this can easily fail (especially with an aplha month abbreviation that is only valid in certain language settings and with a timezone that must be taken in consideration). If one had wanted the database to see this as a datetime they would have chosen an appropriate type. So leave it as is and only interprete it outside. You say this comes from JavaScript? Then read it with JavaScript and do your calculations there.

Comment: Sounds like a poorly implemented key/value table. However, as mentioned, as long as you don't work with the data in the database but only store it, it's okay. (That also means what I already said: with the data model given, don't perform the calculations in the DBMS.)

Answer (score 2):

You shoud really use mysql [Date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) type. *(Edit: Just saw in the comment why you're using varchar, so let's skip that ;) )*

Anyway, you can try to cast your strings into dates using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    SECOND,
    STR_TO_DATE('Fri Nov 25 2016 12:09:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', '%a %b %d %Y %T'),
    STR_TO_DATE('Fri Nov 25 2016 12:20:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', '%a %b %d %Y %T')
)
```

Comment: Works so long as all the dates are in the same timezone - the Timezone component will be ignored with this so comparing those 2 times gives 660 seconds but it also gives 660 seconds if you change one of those to use GMT+0100 as the Timezone.

Comment: Yep you're right.MySQL does not have a dedicated data type for storing timezone, so on DATE_FORMAT. We must do the TZ diff aside of this query :o

Comment: Works so long as all the dates are in the same timezone, how to do if it different timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('Nov 25 2016 12:09:34','Fri Nov 25 2016 12:20:34') as diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dat1 = "Fri Nov 26 2016 12:09:34 GMT+0530";
$dat2 = "Fri Nov 25 2016 12:20:34 GMT+0530";

$diff = abs(strtotime($dat2) - strtotime($dat1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Comment: Sheesh - talk about making life difficult for yourself, you can do date comparisons if you use DateTime objects : http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php